# remove all list elements starting with a hash

Tags: python

i have a list with elements, some of which start with "#". how can i remove those elements?
I tried:

```
content = [x for x in content[][0] if x != "#"]
```

but:

```
content[][0]
```

seems to be not valid. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
content = [x for x in content if not x.startswith('#')]
```

Comment: In-place method: `content[:] = [x for x in content if not x.startswith('#')]`

Comment: @Manny D - Yep, that's a nice addition.

Answer (score 2):

The same can be done with python built-in filter method:

```
content = filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('#'), content)
```

But note that in both cases you are not removing - you creating a new one list.

Comment: Note this returns a python filter iterator object - wrap it in a `list()` if you need this: `content = list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('#'), content))`

Answer (score 0):

```
skip_char = ('!!','==','**','#')
result[:] = [item for item in content if not item.startswith(skip_char)]
```

remove or skip all list elements or items starting with a # and !! and == and **.
You can pass as **tuple** for future changes in skip section.

or add multiple condition in one line to remove items that start with "!! and == and ** and #"

```
[item for item in content if not item.startswith('!!') and not item.startswith('==') and not item.startswith('**') and not item.startswith('#')]
```