# Python List Manipulation With Regex

Tags: python, regex, list

Let's say I have the following list:

```
my_list = ["<stuff","10","20","John","<td testing"]
```

I want to go through each value in the list and remove it if it contains a "<" at the start of the value.

My final result should look like this:

```
my_list = ["10","20","John"]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove all list elements starting with a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058679/remove-all-list-elements-starting-with-a-hash)

Comment: ^^^ Very similar question

Comment: ` [i for i in ["<stuff","10","20","John","<td testing"] if not i.startswith('<')]`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `regex` to achieve this. A simple *list comprehension* with [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) will work:

```
>>> my_list = ["<stuff","10","20","John","<td testing"]

>>> [s for s in my_list if not s.startswith("<")]
['10', '20', 'John']
```

Alternative using `filter()` with *lambda expression*:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("<"), my_list))
['10', '20', 'John']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `startswith` method for `str` objects as:

```
my_list = ["<stuff","10","20","John","<td testing"]
my_list = [elt for elt in my_list if not elt.startswith("<") ]
print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
['10', '20', 'John']
```